# Обработчик интерфейса любого T типа

Tags: c#, generics

```
public interface IFoo<T> { }
public class FooStr : IFoo<string> { }
public class FooInt : IFoo<int> { }
public class FooObj : IFoo<object> { }
public class FooHandler<T> where T : IFoo<...> { } // ???
...
FooHandler<FooStr> fooHandlerStr = new FooHandler<FooStr>();
FooHandler<FooInt> fooHandlerInt = new FooHandler<FooInt>();
FooHandler<FooObj> fooHandlerObj = new FooHandler<FooObj>();
```

Как написать класс, `T` которого `IFoo<>` с любым `U`?

Comment: Стоит указать, что именно не так. Показанный код не работает? Что такое "обработчик"? Метод? Класс? На что это должно быть похоже? Если что-то обрабатывается, значит где-то какие-то аргументы в метод должны передаваться, или что-то возвращаться должно? Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: @aepot, в этом и прикол, я хочу без указания `X`. `IFoo<X>` уже подрузомевает некий `X` и я не хочу его указывать, перегружая бестолковой информацией.

Comment: Причем не только беcтолковой но и вредной! Тут заложен конфликт что, если указать не тот тип `X` который реализует `T`, код ломается.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.27.php - здесь точно ничего полезного нет? Если X это родитель классов, то можно сделать контрвариантный или ковариантный интерфейс. А был бы смысл в этом, но точно не узнать имея перед глазами конкретной реализации. Что хотите - понятно, непонятно - зачем?

Comment: `static void FooHandler<T>(IFoo<T> foo) { }` - не?

Comment: По ссылке типа ограничений типов `<T>`. Ты написал статический метод, а мне нужен класс.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541173/5045688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на англоязычном stack: [C# generic "where constraint" with "any generic type" definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541173/12097500)

Спасибо @AlexanderPetrov.

---

```
public interface IFoo { }
public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo { }
public class FooHandler<U> where U : IFoo { }
```

Очень элегантный способ, но при котором не удастся использовать обобщение `T` в аргументах `FooHandler`.

---

```
public interface IFoo { }
public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo { }
public class FooHandler<U, T> where U : IFoo<T> { }
```

Очевидный вариант, если `T` типа `IFoo` нужно использовать в аргументах `FooHandler`.

---

Варианта, где `T` может автоматически взяться из `U`, к сожалению не существует, язык такого пока что не позволяет.

- `U` нужно мануально указывать повторно
- не только в `FooHandler` но и в всех его обобщенных наследниках, нужно писать `where U : IFoo<T>`, что бы `U` который ты указываешь мануально не мог отличаться от того, который реализует `IFoo`
- 

Comment: Галку воткнуть в ответ не забудь.